# Why is it difficult to write the close loop transfer function of a frequency modulated DC-DC converter (for eg - LLC converter)?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, resonance, frequency-modulation, duty-cycle

I know how to derive and write the transfer function of duty cycle/pulse width modulated DC-DC converter. We need to linearize the switches and then write KVL/KCL equations and then derive the output to duty cycle transfer function.
I do not fully understand the Mathematical/ technical reasons why it is so hard to derive the transfer function of a frequency modulated DC-DC converter (for eg - LLC resonant converters).

Comment: Averaged modeling is done by considering that energy is conveyed by the *average* value of the waveforms, independent from their frequency. This is the principle behind the PWM switch model for instance, in which the switching components has disappeared. With resonant converters such as LLCs, energy is transported by the fundamental and its harmonics. As such, it complicates the analysis since you have to *describe* state variables by their frequency content (and it differs whether you operate at or above/below resonance) and then linearize to obtain an approximate small-signal model.

Comment: Thank You. When there is pulse width modulation the time period T is the same (even though the ON/OFF time might be different) so the phrase "average value of the waveforms, independent from their frequency" is Valid.
But in frequency modulation the T(time period) is itself different, is it because of that, the "independent from their frequency" phrase doesn't hold?